# Why numpy.int16 becomes numpy.float64 after I bit masking?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to bit masking and discard the LSB of my data[], a numpy.ndarray containing int16. data = [2,0,4,......,-2,-4]
So I create a new array and by bit masking with -2, which should be 1111111111111110 in terms of 16-bit binary.

```
data_new = np.zeros(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
    data_new[i] = np.int16(data[i] & -2)
```

Somehow, the output is not array of int16. It becomes numpy.float64. And python doesn't allow me to do a bitwise OR to rewrite the LSB.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'numpy.float64' and 'int'
>>type(data[0])
numpy.int16
>>type(data_new[0])
numpy.float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dtype` of the array returned by `numpy.zeros` defaults to `float64`. If you want a different type, either explicitly pass the `dtype`, e.g.:

```
data_new = np.zeros(len(data), np.int16)
```

or if `data` was already the right size and `dtype`, use `np.zeros_like` to copy its format and structure:

```
data_new = np.zeros_like(data)
```

Mind you, in this particular case, the correct solution is likely to just let `numpy` do the masking and new array creation in bulk, implicitly, by replacing your creation of the array and loop to populate it with just:

```
data_new = data & -2
```

which will run *much* faster, and "just work" (it will have the same size and `dtype` as `data` automatically).

Comment: Thanks !!! You really save my life here. I didn't know that numpy.zeros defaults to float64. And are you suggesting that I can directly run data_new = data & -2 without declaring data_new and initialize it as 0 at first?

Comment: WOW. I just tried data_new = data & -2 and it is so much faster !.

Comment: Do you know if I can do bit wise OR based on this data_new ? If my data_new is [0,1,1,..] and in binary it is [0000, 0001, 0001]. And I want to OR with 1 (0001), can I simply do data_new | 1 ?

Comment: @Iloveece: I think you should be using `np.bitwise_or()` and `np.bitwise_and()` to perform bit-wise operations element-wise

Comment: @fountainhead: Plain `|` works fine; `data | 1` (or to modify in place, `data |= 1`) will set the low bit of every element.  The named functions are fine, but completely unnecessary unless you need to customize the destination, change the `dtype` as you go, etc. For basic bitwise OR-ing, `|` is more straightforward.